# C++ Singleton - Prevent ::instance() to variable

Tags: c++, singleton

## Given the singleton class

```cpp
class MySingleton
{
    // ...
    public:
        MySingleTon& instance() { /* ... */ }
};
```

is it possible to prevent:

```cpp
int main()
{
    // the following should cause some error
    MySingleton& singleton = MySingleton::instance();
}
```

while still allowing:

```cpp
int main()
{
    // Only directly accessing MySingleton::instance().SomeMethod should be possible
    MySingleton::instance().some_method();
}
```

## Extra example

```cpp
int main()
{
    // Following two lines should error
    MySingleton& singleton = MySingleton::instance();
    singleton.some_method();
    
    // Following line should NOT error
    // Additionally it should be the only way to access any MySingleton method besides MySingleton::instance
    MySingleton::instance().some_method();
}
```

Comment: No, it's not possible. Also, consider using a namespace instead of a class for your singleton - the syntax won't change, but you won't have any needs for that `instance`. Unless, of course, you need to lazily create some global data. In addition - **why** would you want to prevent having a reference to your instance? What's the point?

Comment: Why would capturing it to a variable be a problem? If it's a singleton it shouldn't ever move or become invalidated.

Comment: Cannot tell you @tadman. As i said, original question is not from me but rather caused me to attempt to prevent that with which i failed. I do not embrace the idea but found it interesting enough to actually ask if someone smarter has some solution to this rather odd "design choice"

Comment: I'm just trying to get to the bottom of what seems to be an XY Problem and understand your motivation here. There's really not much you can do to prevent someone from capturing it to a variable short of not returning a value, which sort of makes that function completely useless. In C++ if a function returns a value you can always capture that into a variable. I'm not even sure you can make this difficult, as references are always allowed even if copies aren't.

Comment: The original user who asked that question in an IRC had indeed some XY Problem going on. But this question really just relates to wether there is some way to prevent a variable of `MySingleton` with any modifiers to exist and enforce the use of `MySingleton::instance()` to access any methods.

Comment: `auto& singleton = MySingleton::instance();` sidesteps all attempts to prevent this

Comment: that is pretty much the issue i stopped at too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know to do what you are looking for is to make `instance()` itself be `private` so code that is outside of `MySingleton` can't call it directly, then add a `static` method to `MySingleton` that is `public` and uses `instance()` internally as needed, eg:

```
class MySingleton
{
    // ...
    private:
        MySingleton() { /* ... */ }
        static MySingleton& instance() {  static MySingleton inst; return inst; }
    public:
        static void do_method() { instance().some_method(); }
};

int main()
{
    MySingleton& singleton = MySingleton::instance(); // <-- ERROR
    singleton.some_method();
    
    MySingleton::do_method(); // <-- OK
}
```

Comment: this is actually some very great idea. Though it requires to "redefine" every method as static pass-through